# Is there a way to compile an AMD based miner for use on a mac?

Tags: gpu-mining, xmr-stak-amd

I have an iMac with a R9 M395 2048 MB for its GPU. I know mac normally has nvidia GPUs nowadays but somehow this one had a mac AMD gpu.

Is there someway I can compile a linux or windows based AMD GPU miner to run on my mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
brew install openssl libmicrohttpd
git clone -b dev https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-amd
cd xmr-stak-amd
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ ..
make
```

It may be necessary to insert the following line in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
```

To run the executable:

```
cp bin/xmr-stak-amd ..
cd ..
./xmr-stak-amd config.txt
```

Note that the `config.txt` file and the `opencl` folder should be on the same location as the executable `xmr-stak-amd`.

You'd need to tweak the `config.txt` file to figure out the best setting for your GPU. To get you started, I've posted below the worst performing setting that should work on any GPU:

https://gist.github.com/stoffu/fa9a35928e0f6325f9d379c2d902d7cc

Relevant post on Reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6cla1s/can_someone_please_help_me_to_compile_xmrstakcpu/dkubnr4/

Comment: Thank you. These instructions did make it work, unfortunately I'm sure there's a bunch of things  that I need to tune(ex: thread affinity doesn't matter on mac, at least thats what the xmr-stak-cpu i compiled says when I run that one). I'll have to play with the config file